# Java Sound, Converting Percentage Volume to Decibels

Tags: java, decibel, javax.sound.sampled

I have the following code.

```
FloatControl volumeControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

// Set the value to modify by in decibels
volumeControl.setValue(float volume);
```

Get minimum modification value in decibels (e.g. -80)

```
volumeControl.getMinimum();
```

Get maximum modification value in decibels (e.g. 6)

```
volumeControl.getMaximum();
```

I have a `float` called `volume`, which ranges from -1f (sound completely off) to +1f (200% volume).

How do I convert `volume` to the number of decibels to modify the `volumeControl` by?

Comment: It's not totally clear if `volume` is intended to be relative to the total volume range, or is intended to be the volume delta relative to current volume. If it's intended to be relative to the total volume range, then you need to map the range of `volume` to the range of `volumeControl`, e.g. `volumeDecibels = 43 * (volume + 1.0f) - 80`

Comment: @BenSimmons, ah apologies. It is supposed to be relative to whatever volume the song is playing at currently (since decibels are logarithmic).